# Page Header in LaTeX for a memoir

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, memoir, titles

The document class I am using is:

`\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany,leqno,footinclude=true]{memoir}`

I want to get the header of a page in LaTeX just like the one I found here:

[image]

Here apparently Abstract is a section. How can I recreate the headings given in this page?

Comment: Package `titling` could help, but it should be possible even with simple LaTeX commands

Comment: What do you mean 'have to'? Says who? Note that any answer is likely to be useless unless you post a small, sample document because the answer will depend on the class you are using. But, for standard classes, `titling` is certainly good.

Comment: @cfr I put the details

Comment: @ferrer: Details? ;-) Fragments

Comment: Abstract isn't a section, by the way.

Comment: @cfr okay. Maybe a chapter ? or just bold text ?? How did you find it out by looking ?

Comment: @ferrer Neither. It is a specialised environment. I read about it in chapter 5 of the manual.  It isn't anything but itself, if you see what I mean.  Apparently **memoir** incorporates the **abstract** package, although I've never used the latter so that did not help me very much. Also, I tried adding `\section{something}` and saw that it got formatted completely differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this has to reproduced, but this is a starter (only), without a further package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany,leqno]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

{%
\centering
{%
\large 
\textsc{Transport Architectures for an evolving internet}%

by

\textsc{Keith Winstein}%
}
\vskip\baselineskip
Submitted to the Department of Silly Walks

}




\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just don't use semantic markup at all?

Comment: @cfr: No, I am lazy ;-) I don't see the advantage of wrapping macros around this header if there is not much to configure and designed for a one - time usage only (at least I've understood the question this way)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The submitted to silly walks line doesn't centre itself like above. I tried enclosing it in \centring but still it doesn't.

Comment: @ferrer: Yes, sorry, I forgot use an empty line after `Submitted` -- `centering` needs that -- see the update

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks. I put \begin{center}.. for that.

Comment: @ferrer: That's possible to, but introduces more vertical spacing above and below the header then

Comment: This breaks the use of, for example, `\thetitle` and `\theauthor` etc. and possibly other things. (I don't know the class well enough to be sure what else, if anything.) @ferrer

Comment: @cfr: Why ??? I don't use any `memoir` internals at all and `\maketitle` can be used at any place

Comment: Because your way does not use `\title{}` or `\author{}` so `\thetitle{}` and `\theauthor{}` aren't set appropriately. Of course, you could *also* do `\title{}` and `\author{}` but then if you change the version in your code, you must remember to change those as well. It is because the class essentially incorporates **titling** (and **abstract**). And you are throwing the advantages of that away for no good reason.

Comment: @cfr: I understood the question that the name of the person in the heading is not the name of the `\author`  of the whole document. In this sense, my solution is 'correct', by not using `\author` etc.

Comment: You can use `\author{}` multiple times and `\title{}` and `\date{}` and issue as many `\maketitle` as you like, with `\thetitle` etc. available as you wish. If what you say is true, there is *more* reason to do this - not less - since it is more likely you might want this information in the headers/footers in this case.

Comment: @cfr: Perhaps, but the OP was happy with this solution so I keep it, if he finds your way better he should transfer the tick to your post and I'll delete my apparently 'rubbish' solution

Comment: I did not describe your solution that way. Moreover, it would be very easy to adapt your solution to simply use `\thetitle` and `\theauthor` in place of the literal strings.

Answer (score 3):

Memoir includes code based on both the **titling** and **abstract** packages so you should use these facilities for modifying the layout.

The abstract is not a section but, rather, a specialised environment of its own with its own settings and configuration.

Note that using Memoir's tools for configuring the title means that the relevant pieces of data are available throughout the document for use in, for example, headers or footers, if required. Hence, there are advantages to setting things up so that you use `\title{}`, `\author{}` etc., even if you do not use the customisation macros provided by the class itself. (In fact, for a separate title page, the manual recommends not using the `\maketitle` configuration, but doing it manually. But you'd still want to do it so that your title page used the values passed to `\title{}`, `\author{}` etc.

The relevant chapters of the manual are 4 and 5 as indicated in the annotations below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany,leqno,footinclude=true]{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
% see chapter 4 of memoir's documentation
\pretitle{\begin{center}\large\scshape}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{%
  \begin{center}
    \large\scshape \lineskip 0.5em%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
}
\postauthor{%
  \end{tabular}
  \par
  \end{center}%
}
\predate{}
\postdate{}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookb{\centering by\par}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc{%
  \begin{center}
    Submitted to the Department of Astro-Engineering of the Intergalactic University at Alpha Centauri on May 29, 3014 \textsc{CE} in partial fulfilment of the degree of Doctor of Philosophy
  \end{center}%
}
% ref: chapter 5 of memoir's manual
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushleft}
\setlength\absleftindent{0pt}
\setlength\absrightindent{0pt}

\title{Transport Architectures for an Evolving Internet}
\author{Keith Winstein}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \noindent The purpose of \thetitle{} is to establish the feasibility of adapting ships designed for intergalatic travel for interepoch travel.
  This works turns, therefore, on crucial correspondences between the engineering problems presented by changes of spatial location and those presented by changes of temporal location.
\end{abstract}

\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: customised formatting for title and abstract]

If you also need to customise the formatting of chapters, sections etc., then you should look at the manual and follow the instructions there. The class offers an extensive set of chapter styles, along with facilities for configuring the headings of lower sectional divisions.

## EDIT

To make the advantages of using semantic mark-up here clear, suppose that the document does, indeed, include work by various authors under various title. Perhaps this is a compilation of abstracts interspersed with plagiarised paragraphs borrowed by those authors from Kant.

Then we can produce a layout including several occurrences of `\maketitle` - one per author/title - and the corresponding abstracts together with an additional paragraph (from Kant) under the author's name on a new page. Using the page styles provided by the class, we create a header with the page number on the left and the author and title on the right:

[image: many authors/titles]

So this markup is *especially* useful in a document which includes titles/abstracts by several authors or by authors other than the author of the original document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany,leqno,footinclude=true]{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
% see chapter 4 of memoir's documentation
\pretitle{\begin{center}\large\scshape}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{%
  \begin{center}
    \large\scshape \lineskip 0.5em%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
}
\postauthor{%
  \end{tabular}
  \par
  \end{center}%
}
\predate{}
\postdate{}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookb{\centering by\par}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc{%
  \begin{center}
    Submitted to the Department of Astro-Engineering of the Intergalactic University at Alpha Centauri on May 29, 3014 \textsc{CE} in partial fulfilment of the degree of Doctor of Philosophy
  \end{center}%
}
% ref: chapter 5 of memoir's manual
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushleft}
\setlength\absleftindent{0pt}
\setlength\absrightindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{companion}
\makeevenhead{companion}{\thepage}{}{\theauthor: \thetitle}

\title{Transport Architectures for an Evolving Internet}
\author{Keith Winstein}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \noindent The purpose of \thetitle{} is to establish the feasibility of adapting ships designed for intergalatic travel for interepoch travel.
  This works turns, therefore, on crucial correspondences between the engineering problems presented by changes of spatial location and those presented by changes of temporal location.
\end{abstract}
\newpage
\kant[1]
\clearpage

\title{Transformative Archaeology for a Devolved Intranet}
\author{Weith Kinstein}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \noindent The purpose of \thetitle{} is to establish the feasibility of retraining archaeologists steeped in centralised concepts so that they can effectively manage discovery-based research focused on intranet devolution.
  This works turns, therefore, on crucial correspondences between the conceptual difficulties encountered by archaeologists working within centralised networks and those encountered by archaeologists working within devolved networks.
\end{abstract}
\newpage
\kant[2]

\title{Transitive Adaptions for a Revolutionary Internet}
\author{Theki Steiwin}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \noindent The purpose of \thetitle{} is to establish the feasibility of adapting networks designed for establishment usage for use by the Glorious Revolution.
  This works turns, therefore, on crucial correspondences between the problems encountered by pre-revolutionary state actions and those encountered by their post-revolutionary counterparts.
\end{abstract}
\newpage
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```